# PreRex not making Arrows

Tags: arrows

I am trying to make a pre-requisite chart as shown in the MWE below. The issue I'm having is I'm just getting lines instead of arrows. [image: flowchartwitharros]Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
%\geometry{noheadfoot,vmargin=1.0in, hmargin=0.5in}
\usepackage{prerex}
\usepackage{helvet}


\begin{document}
\Huge{MTH 251+ Pre-Requisite FlowChart}

\Large
\thispagestyle{empty}

\setcounter{diagheight}{50}
\begin{chart}
\reqhalfcourse 40,45:{251}{Calculus I}{}

\reqhalfcourse 40,35:{252}{Calulus II}{}
  \prereq 40,45,40,35:

\reqhalfcourse 20,25:{261}{Linear Algebra}{}
 \prereq 40,35,20,25:

 \reqhalfcourse 60,25:{253}{Calculus III}{}
\prereq 40,35,60,25:

  \reqhalfcourse 60,15:{254}{Calculus IV}{}
 \prereq 60,25,60,15:

  \reqhalfcourse 20,15:{256}{Differential Equations}{}
 \prereq 20,25,20,15:
 \recomm 60,15,20,15:

\end{chart}
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}{6.0in}

A solid arrow \solidarrow\  indicates a required prerequisite and a
dashed arrow \dashedarrow\ indicates a recommended prerequisite.


\end{minipage}
\end{center}


\end{document}
```

and this is the output I get[image: flowchartwithoutarrows]. What's going on? Am I missing something that would get the arrows to show up?

Comment: Not sure if you ever figured this one out, but anyway, if you didn't, and are still  wondering: Your example works fine here, with an up to date TeX Live 2016. Can you add `\listfiles` before `\documentclass`, run `pdflatex` again, and edit your question to include the `.log` file?